# Cant generate Hasse Diagram using R

Tags: r, error-handling, diagram

I am getting error when the following code is run

```
data0_0 <- hasseDiagram::generateRandomData(15, 2, 0.0)
data0_5 <- hasseDiagram::generateRandomData(15, 2, 0.5)
data1_0 <- hasseDiagram::generateRandomData(15, 2, 1.0)
hasseDiagram::hasse(data0_0)
hasseDiagram::hasse(data0_5)
hasseDiagram::hasse(data1_0)
```

The error is

```
> source('~/test.r')
Error in .class1(object) : could not find function "graphAM"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cause of your error is that you don't load and attach other packages that `hasseDiagram` depend on. If you have those packages, `library("hasseDiagram")` will solve your problem. (many of them aren't on the CRAN repository but you can get newest [graph](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/graph.html), [BiocGenerics](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocGenerics.html) and [Rgraphviz](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html) package via Bioconductor 3.3).

```
library("hasseDiagram")
data0_5 <- generateRandomData(15, 2, 0.5)
hasse(data0_5)
```

[image]